# Android Studio - Logcat stops working after file upload

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I've noticed lately while running my app from Android Studio, after uploading any file, the Logcat seems to stop functioning. The last thing I will see will be the post data, which includes a long string of file data, and then it goes silent. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: q�X����ܚ� 1��g�{צkCp�,��+�튺�|Փ��"�,�b`��R1�"Q��Fl�};Չ'�|Q,�'�t��c�b>p�J̓W%v�����1g��z�M�<Q,3޲��IL���  ��'$ �t���v������Cϱ�I�$���4�d
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Ob�P��$[\�)�B���@��۰���H���K�l6��T����P&L��J"���4ِ���c��8�+ɬ�\Kl�"le�[ċ�c�HRHw+��������������MqY[<f��G�g�sWmb�� �_�T2(Q�hy����h����R���������`���5$d�O=��H�~W98�՜��>��}u2�,a�,3Z�G��C��Wxf2pN1PC�N�­og��Uʌ�O5���D�U�o��S,��U%���Z��L��X��bu��4��S.|�N�9�of�3�5�J�fܔʾiP�OJ�Y�w �U�z�l�G���#}�8�z�*��9�4�:-3���,rHH��N;�mż�����C�4�����V��s���A},hr�!
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: }]6���Q��v,X��H$�(/,b5�$�=�.�si?xqQ�1�Z�l��W�<57aU�x,p�ӎ��E��ْIN��X�u9�7��
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: ������e�n손��C�EF�f�Ĩڤ�x�\���F���ިk��oj�&���djZ��rY: ��JZ�JZ�rE[�rz�TQ�4���R�w�������*8�iD�(�y �ѕʸ�v�/��I�V����5��0���1��$�s���7O������{�s�z��TI�H T��2)5F1B���p   ��I����I��⼠�0p��(��Ud���4c�S����5qb�    8�gV    �҅Iө�.����$��Ml��4Y{W'����P��e�߭tv,�9=��1s��~��b%R�L���qґ�� U)�h��`�l$��5���b;i)�]�$�sL?+`Rơ�)�i�   �2)��&����,,�J�܊���ɗ�e%fr�vd*L�n�,q�2���'�ЖrcDE��KUN�{��E\��Vd_ƖY���+�;J�+q��Z��eR�EU�8���z~5�K����h��ۘㅌx�(�3RjlE���j���$��b�rl�2�ڴ�x=)�l����W�fa���J��'��ͣ!�����R!]ې�u���I�#�Y�fs�=i��茙��j/�߭����^���WQ(�Q�g�ybƮ�p�Z��A�@��eM>���ǚ+�#qTu�.�9銏Cv[T
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: �f��,��r���+͌��l�nbv�Xu�2�<8�V릟i��w�Չ������;ڒ�8�b\"i^]�i�X��oM'��W��w�܃Y������+�p�c��<�Vz\͉.��7*1����Yq,rFs����;��AVEĲY���6�f��U���9�nI��V7nO�ř��H�+"�yD�Nrj՝ī�CtQF�.X;3�θ���J���eF{�٥g�b�&   �;+y��*d�CZ�R�-H��B뚑�#�@Y^�Oi
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: ��sT����~`85�����Ne�c�P��YP�z
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: ����&v%��Hee��.��G"h�z���AoQW�h@Q���Y�������׊���y"�x�qF\�яTkyʼE��)�Z
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: ���q��ҳ�A�5%úBv9/j�Q�e��6R瓑U6�Ĥ�9<�t�VH�W$�<j�,|�<�M�˱v�)w[�����4�;��R@�|�1��(�f�'Q��&���T9={z�m��    ����5>�Y�
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: H�/�S]�
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: �JD��
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: rv�~�m!Yn$�}�|���f�R�++c��x�q���{3����\��$��A�Ē94�Z�  l������.���1���m�F�M�h3��;da������Ð���&��$�����8m!�˷�prs\5�:�ͭM-+[������+   ��PŹ�p��/#��+��db���a�V�H$Ύ��۶�5��x�m�|��}됷���Iȫ��B�W3�=i�K����kp����n�\d�� �#���Һ�?�~��2gU�����Cg�Ҵ�k"�Fٷ<T�4��k��l�c�kS���60���װ�r�޹[GbFMmilK
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: ��s�X�b��P*h԰�j��o\���o�2h��X�Ƞ(�[ޚ   �Wڥ�I�\��A�T��3ڗ&���������OJ������r����U�-����"�O�X���5�I���t5���/�2�n���*z�:W7�ߵ���8ϭz����-���+˼Z�o�m�m�t��6KC��Ւ�7n+Z�p�s^{��\��Nj����sڪ2�V/��qQ��9X������;�Ȅ�czU��1�zk�G�VMʲFG8��T�H�]bXm'��D]�*�J�ֱ��+�dI��oʠt�
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: +�VPx�tE�͛MlBJy���vP�6���:���AO�)���Z�#ɼ[�������r�ix[���E#������U�Y\سM��b}G�y��ih�-��1��9n�l�m/\���T>Oֵap���k�|yr��[��c8�zn�wE����Q���T�r����`9�E��§�^�oB0pr)�Ĝm*�sV�EY�����GZ%bTTJr3R��n8�H*��* H9���MM�+�Y������*���Fi7�;��A�h�ڝ��5��5�8���N����,�IGS_Ic �k�V�Z{    �V�+U�}�~A|P�U��J�{i-29��?���Nd��:������w�tX�t����m|i�R�'co\�k����*8V�]B0������
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: �km�eLOrƶ4�^#'��Ɏ@ŇJ�J�ҝY�̒-� PP�t�\0���/#"��\��G�JW*ˬ    �Y�
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: %�t�`ƪ�5є�w�R��w��'����g�۱�Ajh�� +�G#4��"�2�/P+&�i&»�8�;X�M�ý8N�l�����l:������^�]��%
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: ����FO+E�*ƅ�c��N�a�h<�ɤ���v9��{�Ew
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: �}>���d�fT���.B��7C�Ҵ��.o���v�V[���+gO��dB��{TNDܹ�w�>^��)/�&�|��֊��cҝ-��r�6ޢ����i�RE�.rX`b�l�H��"w���+O�X�B�ӧ�C�}F�P����0�`;f��Ma�f�έ�L���^��\�������|������[�0��A��U�ج@��^L��suI3��
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: --7a3e6f77-cfbb-4790-add6-e1cf1502685e
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entry_count"
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 1
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: 1
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: --7a3e6f77-cfbb-4790-add6-e1cf1502685e
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="timestamp"
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 12
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: 200218123127
2020-02-18 12:31:27.710 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: --7a3e6f77-cfbb-4790-add6-e1cf1502685e--
2020-02-18 12:31:27.711 26031-26622/org.lakeobserver.observer.android.debug D/OkHttp: --> END POST (2207027-byte body)
```

Update: 
When running Logcat on the command line it also crashes out. I get the following error:

```
02-19 10:08:37.954   646 20799 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)
02-19 10:08:38.262  2428  2428 I CarrierServices: Æ2Å clo.onReceive: Received SERVICE_STATE intent, clearing cached cell info
02-19 10:08:38.268  1831  1831 D ServiceStateProvider: subId=1
02-19 10:08:38.267 15396 15396 D CellBroadcastReceiver: onReceive Intent æ act=android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE flg=0x1000010 cmp=com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver/.CellBroadcastReceiver (has extras) å
read: unexpected EOF!
```

Comment: This is specifically the Logcat inside Android Studio, right? I've always had trouble with that feature; seems super buggy. I know this doesn't really answer your question, but have you tried running Logcat from the command line instead? Also, does the same thing happen when you try to upload an empty file?

Comment: I haven't tried running Logcat from command lline, and I haven't tried uploading an empty file. I'll try both of those and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw something similar to this problem. Logcat on the app I work on would stop working after a few (mp4) file uploads done via multipart upload on Retrofit. The number of files that logcat would survive past varied, but was never more than 10 or so.

We have an interceptor in our ApiClient file thus:

```
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        }
```

Given your logcat output, it looks like you may be using Retrofit as well.

**Fix:**
When I disabled the interceptor (wrapping it in /* */) logcat churned happily along. If you are using an interceptor for your http traffic, consider disabling it. I know this is not a very nice solution and it won't be much help if you are not using an interceptor to log your http traffic, but it might help logcat to last long enough to see the output you are interested in.